# QTabWidget with tabs both at the top and to the right.

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtabwidget, qtstylesheets

I have a `QTabWidget` with two tabs. I want one to be on the east side and the other one at the top.

I've tried these style sheets, but so far I couldn't get it right.

```
#tab_basic::top{
}

#tab_advanced::right{
}
```

or

```
#tab_basic{
position:top;
}

#tab_advanced{
position:right;
}
```

or

```
#tab_basic::top{
}

#tab_advanced::east{
}
```

or

```
#tab_basic{
position:top;
}

#tab_advanced{
position:east;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't accomplish this with the `QTabWidget` as far as I know. What you could do is to create two QTabBar widgets and lay them out the way you want in a `QGridLayout`. As a center widget you can use a `QStackedWidget` and depending on which tab that is activated you can control what widget of the `QStackedWidget` to be visible.

Comment: I'll try that approach. Thank you very much.